# How do I add my exported Item Template to the Web group under Visual C# in the Add New Item dialog in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've exported a `C#` `Item Template` for use in `Visual Studio 2013`. In the `Add New Item` dialog, it appears in the `Visual C#` category by default. That's okay, but I really want it in the Visual C# subcategory `Web`. I've modified the `MyTemplate.vstemplate` file the best way I can understand (using the [ProjectType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5we0w25d.aspx) and [ProjectSubType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171386.aspx) elements) and have the following results:

```
 <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
    <TemplateData>
        <DefaultName>DefaultName.aspx</DefaultName>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Description>Item template description</Description>
        <ProjectType>Web</ProjectType>
        <ProjectSubType>CSharp</ProjectSubType>
        <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    </TemplateData>
...
</VSTemplate>
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.